# VS Code has a star (★) in the property name

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, ide

Recently, I've noticed that some of the JavaScript\TypeScript objects, in VS Code, has a starred properties. What does that mean?

Example:
I've defined an array of strings - 'myArray'
[image]

Comment: I think you might be using [intelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode), or a similar intellisense extension.

Comment: [Same question for Visual Studio 2019+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59398968/1366033)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As [Yannick K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11417877/yannick-k) pointed out correctly the stars come from the [IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode) extension and aim to mark the most commonly used attributes and methods.