# Why is IntelliSense showing a star to the left of functions within if statements

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.4.1

IntelliSense is  showing a star icon to the left of `IsNullOrEmpty`. Not sure what it means.

[image: IsNullOrEmpty screenshot]

**Edit 1:**
It's not just `IsNullOrEmpty`

[image: System.Activities.Activity screenshot]

**Edit 2**
It only shows the star within `if()` statement

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's Intellicode at work. Active by default in VS2019 16.1 or later.:

> IntelliCode provides AI-assisted IntelliSense in both Visual Studio
> and Visual Studio Code. IntelliCode suggestions appear at the top of
> the completion list with a star icon next to them.
>
> The completion list suggests the most likely correct API for a
> developer to use rather than presenting a simple alphabetical list of
> members. To provide this dynamic list, IntelliCode uses the
> developer's current code context as well as patterns based on
> thousands of highly rated, open-source projects on GitHub. The results
> form a model that predicts the most likely and most relevant API
> calls.

(From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/overview#context-aware-code-completions )

In this specific case, the `* IsNullOrEmpty` option is the exact same thing as `"IsNullOrEmpty"`.  It is simply being highlighted at the top with the star.  In longer suggestion lists, the recommended method or property might not be immediately visible (requires scrolling before it comes into view).

Comment: I do like this feature.  Is there a way to force an item to be starred for our own code base? I have two similar methods and I always prefer the second over the first, but the AI is unaware of this.

Comment: @DanielWilliams: In this case the AI is simply bad, it doesn't learn correctly.

Comment: @DanielWilliams you can train intellicodebagainst your own codebase. That way the suggestions mirror your own coding practices more. If you upgrade to visual studio 17, this will run automatically in the background: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/upgrading-from-intellicode-custom-team-completions-models-to-deep-learning/

Answer (score 11):

UPDATE (2022/10):

In **VS2022**
To turn it off, use this path:

**Tools** menu, **Options**, **IntelliCode**, **General**, **C# Suggestions**

**VS2019**:

To turn it off, disable **Visual Studio IntelliCode** extension.

**Extensions** menu -> **Installed** -> **Visual Studio IntelliCode**

Comment: It's not causing any trouble to me at least. Useful feature.

Comment: I think in VS2019 this is now `Options` > `Intellicode` > `C# argument completion`, `C# base model`, `C# team models for completion` all disabled.

Comment: I don't understand how do you read the questions... This answer is obviously out of OP as he says: "IntelliSense is showing a star icon to the left of IsNullOrEmpty. Not sure what it means.".

Comment: I don't want to disable IntelliCode, but the stars, because by now they ARE causing trouble.